# I had to drop and restore database again. I was able to drop but got error while restoring. can any one please help me how do i solve this issue

Tags: sql-server

```
use [master]

drop database [databasename]
```

I got following error

> Database could not be dropped  because
>   the database is in use

then i ran following script to deop database and it worked.

```
use [master]
go
Alter Database [databasename]
SET SINGLE_USER With ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
go
go
drop database [databasename]
go
```

then i ran following script and got the error part of which is below the part of script

```
use[master]
IF
EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = N'databasename')
DROP

DATABASE [databasename]
GO
```

i had 5 such drops i took some out here .....for the posting purpose

```
RESTORE

DATABASE [databasename] FROM
DISK 

= N'C:\dbbak\mybatabase.bak' WITH
FILE

= 1,
MOVE

N'my.C.Data' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\databasename.MDF',
MOVE

N'my.C.Log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\databasename.ldf',
NOUNLOAD

, REPLACE, STATS = 10
```

i had some more restores in same manner.

the error i am getting now is

> Database 'databasename' does not
>   exist. Make sure that the name is
>   entered correctly.
>
> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Database 'databasename' does not
>   exist. Make sure that the name is
>   entered correctly.
>
> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to restore or attach?

Are your log files corrupted? Did you try running a DBCC CheckDB beforehand?

What does your DB restore command look like?

BACKUP DATABASE [DBNAme] TO  DISK = N'C:\mylocation\DBName.BAK' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, 
MEDIANAME = N'MediaSet',
 NAME = N'Database-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO

Check and make sure your logical names are the same.

I would also check your locations. Are all your bak files in C:\dbbak\mybatabase.bak?

Are you sure of restore location - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes i have double checked my .bak files they are in the correct location. I am trying to restore. Command is correct because a month ago I used same command to restore. about the restore location yes i am sure about it. I dont know about the log file? since i am new to sql never thought about it. I had dropped database. Do you think log file is still in my system. and if it is where do i find that and how do i solve the problem?